# Using the kronecker product on complex matrices with scalaNLP breeze

Tags: scala, matrix, vector, scala-breeze

I had a piece of code:

```
def this(vectors: List[DenseVector[Double]]) {
    this(vectors.length)
    var resultVector = vectors.head
    for (vector <- vectors) {
        resultVector = kron(resultVector.toDenseMatrix, vector.toDenseMatrix).toDenseVector
    }
    _vector = resultVector
}
```

It worked just the way I wanted it to work. The problem is that I needed complex values in stead of doubles. After importing breeze.math.Complex, I changed the code to:

```
def this(vectors: List[DenseVector[Complex]]) {
    this(vectors.length)
    var resultVector = vectors.head
    for (vector <- vectors) {
       resultVector = kron(resultVector.toDenseMatrix, vector.toDenseMatrix).toDenseVector
    }
    _vector = resultVector
}
```

This however results into the errors:

```
Error:(42, 26) could not find implicit value for parameter impl: breeze.linalg.kron.Impl2[breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[breeze.math.Complex],breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[breeze.math.Complex],VR]
      resultVector = kron(resultVector.toDenseMatrix, vector.toDenseMatrix).toDenseVector
                         ^

Error:(42, 26) not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit impl: breeze.linalg.kron.Impl2[breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[breeze.math.Complex],breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[breeze.math.Complex],VR])VR in trait UFunc.
Unspecified value parameter impl.
      resultVector = kron(resultVector.toDenseMatrix, vector.toDenseMatrix).toDenseVector
                         ^
```

Is this a bug or am I forgetting to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the following way:

1. I first rewrote the function to use less matrix conversions
2. As there was a problem with the implicit `impl` variable of kron, I also rewrote the function call to explicitly state which variable to use to use

.

```
def this(vectors: List[DenseVector[Complex]]) {
    this(vectors.length)
    var resultMatrix = vectors.head.toDenseMatrix
    for (i <- 1 until vectors.length) {
         resultMatrix = kron(resultMatrix, vectors(i).toDenseMatrix)(kron.kronDM_M[Complex, Complex, DenseMatrix[Complex], Complex])
    }
    _vector = resultMatrix.toDenseVector
}
```

This showed me that there was no `ScalarMulOp` for `V2`, `M`, `DenseMatrix[RV]` where `M` is a `Matrix[V1]`, `V1` and `V2` are the input types and `RV` is the output type of the `ScalarMulOp`

Digging through the source code of breeze I found in `DenseMatrixOps` that there only was an implicit `ScalarMulOp` for the above types if `V1`, `V2` and `RV` are of type `Int`, `Long`, `Float` and `Double`. By copying the function and making it specific for Complex numbers, I was able to get the kronecker product to work. Now I could also remove the explicit use of `(kron.kronDM_M[Complex, Complex, DenseMatrix[Complex], Complex])`. The `ScalarMulOp` function in question is:

```
implicit def s_dm_op_Complex_OpMulScalar(implicit op: OpMulScalar.Impl2[Complex, Complex, Complex]):
  OpMulScalar.Impl2[Complex, DenseMatrix[Complex], DenseMatrix[Complex]] =

    new OpMulScalar.Impl2[Complex, DenseMatrix[Complex], DenseMatrix[Complex]] {
      def apply(b: Complex, a: DenseMatrix[Complex]): DenseMatrix[Complex] = {
        val res: DenseMatrix[Complex] = DenseMatrix.zeros[Complex](a.rows, a.cols)
        val resd: Array[Complex] = res.data
        val ad: Array[Complex] = a.data
        var c = 0

        var off = 0
        while (c < a.cols) {
          var r = 0
          while (r < a.rows) {
            resd(off) = op(b, ad(a.linearIndex(r, c)))
            r += 1
            off += 1
          }
          c += 1
        }

        res
      }

      implicitly[BinaryRegistry[Complex, Matrix[Complex], OpMulScalar.type, Matrix[Complex]]].register(this)
    }
```